# Конкретно на данном примере,как реализовать перезапуск анимации css после каждого клика?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function startAnimation() {
  document.getElementById("animation").style.animation = "headShake 1s linear 1";
  return document.getElementById("animation");
}

function startAnimationTwo() {
  document.getElementById("animationTwo").style.animation = "headShake 1s linear 1";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 50px;
}

@keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }
  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }
  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.animate__headShake {
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: headShake;
  animation-name: headShake;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a onclick="startAnimation()">Start</a>
  <a onclick="startAnimationTwo()">Start</a>
  <!--O botão para iniciar (start)-->
  <div id="animation">Hello!</div>
  <div id="animationTwo">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вообще анимация так не делается. Лучше тут будет оперировать классами

Comment: Здравствуйте,в таком случае,если есть источник,где я мог бы почитать как ее лучше реализовать,можете прикрепить?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function startAnimation() {
    document.getElementById("animation").style.animation = "headShake 1s linear 1";
    document.getElementById("animation").addEventListener("animationend", () => {
          document.getElementById("animation").style.animation = "";
    })
}
function startAnimationTwo() {
    document.getElementById("animationTwo").style.animation = "headShake 1s linear 1";
    document.getElementById("animationTwo").addEventListener("animationend", () => {
          document.getElementById("animationTwo").style.animation = "";
    })
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 50px;
}


@keyframes headShake {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  6.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-9deg);
  }

  18.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(7deg);
  }

  31.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }

  43.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(3deg);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
.animate__headShake {
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: headShake;
  animation-name: headShake;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a onclick="startAnimation()">Start</a>
   <a onclick="startAnimationTwo()">Start</a><!--O botão para iniciar (start)-->
   <div id="animation">Hello!</div>
    <div id="animationTwo">Hello!</div>
  </div>
```

Если брать конкретно этот пример то можно так

Comment: Громадное спасибо,очень выручили!

Comment: @WebMaster Изменил код более правильно сделал